# Error no implicit conversion of Hash into String, on using Rack::Test::UploadedFile in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5

I am upgrading from Rails 4 and Ruby 2.1.10 to Rails 5.0.6 and Ruby 2.3.3.

Since `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile` is deprecated in rails 5, I'm using the new way:

```
it "should create candidate" do
  file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new({filename: 'example.csv', type: 'text/csv', tempfile: File.new("#{Rails.root}/spec/files/example.csv")})
  Candidate.import_csv(file)
  expect(Candidate.find_by(name: "Stack Overflow").email).to eq "test@stackoverflow.com"
end
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Hash into String
```

Is the problem caused by random execution of tests?

Comment: Documentation says that `Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new` takes string as an argument, yet you pass hash, which corresponds with your error message.
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/Rack/Test/UploadedFile

Comment: Have seen that, but facing issues in creating the temp file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Marek ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279683/marek-lipka )

```
file = Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new( Rails.root + 'spec/files/example.csv', 'example.csv' )
```